# don't know how to use variables in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
$("#write").click(function(){
    $("#msg").$('#quote').html();

});
```

I am learning jquery (new to js as well). This function writes to a textbox id=msg. However I am having problems pulling the content.

How do I pull the content of a div and use in my function (#quote)? Right now it just writes #quote, not the content of the div called quote.

Also tried:

```
var quote = $("#quote").html();
    $("#msg").$(quote.val).html();
```

Out of ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just like you wrote, but the second line should be `$("#msg").html(quote);`.

The content of #quote is already in `quote`, and in order to replace the content of #msg with it, you pass it as a string to `.html()`.

More about `.html()`: http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: +1 for additional explanation, and for being 9 seconds faster!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was pretty close. So creating a new variable was the only way to do this I guess?

Comment: @Dvir: +1 for beating me by 9 seconds ;)  @domino: You don't have to create a new variable.  You can use: `$('#msg').html( $('#quote').html() );`

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error.  Try this:

```
$("#write").click(function(){
   var quote = $('#quote').html();
   $("#msg").html(quote);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

well I think you should do

```
 $("#msg").val($("#myDiv").html());
```

This will set the value of the div as the value of the textbox.